# Phonegap CLI build plugin cache?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-cli

I'm currently working on **Phonegap 3.1** project. I work locally using the CLI.

I installed (via a remote github repo) a **3rd party plugin using the CLI** which created a directory in the /plugins directory containing 2 sub-directory : src containing the iOS and android native code and a www/ directory containing some .js files.

**When I first build the app for iOS** (still using the CLI) **everything went well** and phonegap did it magic and copied everything at the right place!

However the plugin author made a little mistake on one of the .JS files that I fixed and push requested to his master repo. So I also **made the same correction to the JS file** in the /plugins directory. **However when I recompiled the app it seemed that phonegap ignored my changes** and used my older file. I then made the correction into the /plugins as well as in the /plateforms/ios/... but still after compilation my old files where back! **So I'm wondering if phonegap is redowloading the plugin each time from the repo? or has some kind of building cache...does anyone has a clue??**

This is driving me nuts!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution!

Phonegap has indeed a cache for build.

It create a hidden directory **/plateforms/ios/.staging**

This directory contained a copy of the .JS files that apparently were not updated when rebuilding.

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature...

Hope this will help!

Comment: Did you ever find a command for clearing the cache? I don't have a ```platforms/android/.staging``` folder or I'd try deleting that.